# Cannot Resolve into() method while using Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I use the following code but it is saying that it cannot resolve into() method. What can I do for that?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.description.setText(info.get(position).getDescription());
    Glide.with(context).load(info.get(position).getImage_link().into(holder.imageView));
}
```

And this is my gradle file dependencies:

dependencies {

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:+'
compile 'com.github.karanchuri:PermissionManager:0.1.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.3.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC0'
```

Comment: Why do you have multiple versions of Glide? I think you should only include the latest one remove the other..

Comment: Is that the problem for this condition? What dependencies should I and should not have here? Have you any idea.... I used them all because some dependencies may allow me to use into() method but all of them get failed.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple issues:

1. You have multiple dependencies on Glide. Keep only one and remove the rest. You can find the latest [here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide#download).
2. Your issue is rather simple case of missing parentheses after `get_ImageLink()`. Changing it to this should work:

`Glide.with(context).load(info.get(position).getImage_link()).into(holder.imageView));`